# Setting up a Chainlink node in a Docker container on MacOS (Documentation Issue)

Tags: nodes, chainlink, documentation

I've gotten most of the way through the LINK docs on how to build a chainlink node in container and the only issue I have not been able to trouble shoot is this error I keep getting in my ZSH terminal when trying to build the node in Docker.

Everything starts up normally after a 'docker run...." command but then I get this fatal error:

2023/11/24 20:23:12 OK   0204_create_eal_tables.sql (4.6ms)
2023/11/24 20:23:12 goose: successfully migrated database to version: 204
fatal error instantiating application: networking stack v2 selected but no P2P.V2.ListenAddresses specified

For context I have a Postgresql database running in a separate docker container and I think it is trying to connect to that; also I am using the goerli testnet through infura, although Im pretty sure this error has nothing to do with the blockchain itself.

Comment: I figured it out my chainlink node running in docker was trying to connect to my sql data base running on my desktop rather than the one running in docker, so turning off the desktop Postgres stopped the error from appearing

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my chainlink node running in docker was trying to connect to my sql data base running on my desktop rather than the one running in docker, so turning off the desktop Postgres stopped the error from appearing

Comment: there is also a way to configure that docker does network connections within docker rather than externally to the host machine